# VS2015 Goto Definition shows metadata instead of Object Browser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am used to using the Object Browser when going to a definition since Visual Studio .NET 2002.

This behaviour has changed in VS2015 (VB.NET) for some reason. So now `Goto Definition` command shows confused metadata instead of well-arranged Object Browser.

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Comment: Please don't disparage my coworkers with language like that (I work on Visual Studio)

Comment: If you work on VS, then you can easily tell me the reason of doing such stupidity and how to turn it back to how it was. Thanks.

Comment: I literally don't know what I would do without Visual Studio. It is such a great IDE. I'm sure everything they do has a reason.

Comment: I am still waiting for reason of mentioned thing. By the way, this was not only thing that unpleasantly surprised me after starting VS2015. Dropdown lists in VB.NET code editor gone, need of Internet Explorer 11, Windows Phone/Azure SDKs which cannot be uninstalled...

Comment: @Ondřej by the "dropdown lists" are you referring to the Navigation bar? you have to enable that under Tools > Options > Text Editor > VB.NET > General.

Comment: @Ondřej IE11 is necessary for the updated Trident HTML engine, there is no way around that. If you need older versions of IE for testing please use a VM. Besides it is arguably irresponsible for use an outdated webbrowser on your primary dev machine, not least for security reasons.

Comment: @Ondřej The Windows Phone and Windows Azure SDKs are entirely optional and **can** be uninstalled. Where are you getting that idea from?

Comment: @Dai Yes, I figured how to enable that Navigation bar myself. WHAT was the reason to disable it, it existed since VS2002? Go to Tools/Extensions and Updates, there is Microsoft Azure SDK 2.7, tell me how to get rid of it. What do I care about Trident, I am using Firefox. You still did not answered how to show Object Browser instead of metadata when going to definition.

Comment: @Dai So VS creator, you are unable to help me with your own creation, or you was ordered to stay silent about company's fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Object Browser is finally here! Going to Object Browser/source code option is now available in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. I am very happy.

[image: Go to Definition option]